# What are some good resources for advanced Biblical Hebrew study?

Tags: hebrew, grammar-dikduk

I have been studying Biblical Hebrew for over a year, and have come to the point where I can read most of the prose text in the Hebrew Bible without trouble. I started with a beginner's textbook and have been reading several verses every day. I wish to continue a more formal study of the language by getting a more advanced grammar. What are some good resources to further my study of the language?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I highly recommend Page H. Kelley's - *[Biblical Hebrew: An Introductory Grammar](https://www.google.co.uk/books/edition/A_Handbook_to_Biblical_Hebrew/I_T_waPKq5gC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=kelley%20biblical%20hebrew&printsec=frontcover)* which not only gives the basics, but also provides a comprehensive overview of all the vowels, prefixes, suffixes, prepositions, 'Binyanim' etc. as well as providing exercises so you can put what you have learnt into action.

To quote from one of the [blurbs](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0802874916):

> The book consists of thirty-one lessons, each presenting grammatical concepts with examples and numerous exercises judiciously selected from the biblical text. These lessons are accompanied by eleven complete verb charts, an extensive vocabulary list, a glossary of grammatical terms, and a subject index.

Comment: Thank you. I will try to purchase this book in the future.

Comment: Pleasure! Best of luck with it all